# Perform query once a day

Tags: mysql, database

Basically I have a `MySQL` database with a table that stores requests from the users of my website. I would like to automatically perform a query that removes all completed requests (completed means that the column `Status = 3`) older than 180 days basing on the column `ArchivingDate`.

**My `Requests` table**:

```
Requests(
    RequestID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Ticket VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    RequestDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ReplacementOrRefund INT NOT NULL,
    ItemName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Total NUMERIC(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    AccountName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    BillingAddress VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DeliveryDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    WhoSigned VARCHAR(200),
    WhereLeft VARCHAR(200),
    Status INT NOT NULL,
    ArchivingDate DATETIME,
    PayPalTransactionID VARCHAR(100),
    Toggle TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    StoreID_FK INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (StoreID_FK) REFERENCES Stores(StoreID)
);
```

I have already written the query to remove rows that are older than 180 days:

`$remove = "UPDATE Requests SET Toggle = 0 WHERE Status = 3 AND ArchivingDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)";`

**NOTE:** I do **not** remove data from the table, I simply "hide" it by setting the column `Toggle` to `0`.

**Question:** How do I automatically make MySQL perform this query once a day (if it's possible)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: cron tabs are used to run regularly

Comment: cron tabs? never heard of 'em, do you have any documentation?

Comment: @NicolasD.V. Some (many) webhosts offer cron jobs to be setup using their webhost management of your site if you have one.

Comment: @DTH oh thank you, that's interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's possible, see this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a stored procedure to delete the records based on your criteria of 180 days on "RequestDate" and schedule your stored procedure on daily basis.
Now MySQL will handle the deletion automatically.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will give a look also to stored procedures :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends witch OS you have.

**Linux**

Use file /etc/crontab, add line where specify time and command what to execute.
The columns in crontab file are:**min,hour,day of month,month,day of week,run as user, command**.(Colums are seperated by space)
For example:

30 22 * * * apache php /usr/remove_old.php

It will execute every evening in 22:30.

It is good practice to put the execution result to log file.

30 22 * * * apache php /usr/remove_old.php >> \var\log\removed_requests.log 2>&1

The you can analyze later if somethings goes wrong.

**Windows**

You can use Task Scheduler programm.

Comment: I have Linux, I think imma go with cron tabs. thanks!